# XSLT: How to select siblings with a condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<thesaurus xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <term id="01">
                <name>
            <value>green</value>
        </name>
        <info>
            <ref rid="12" obj-type="Building" />
        </info>
        <info>
            <ref rid="13" obj-type="House" />
        </info>
        <info>
            <ref rid="14" obj-type="Apartment"/>
        </info>
    </term>
    <term id="02">
                <name>
            <value>blue</value>
        </name>
        <info>
            <ref rid="24" obj-type="Unknown"/>
        </info>
        <info>
            <ref rid="26" obj-type="Unknown"/>
        </info>
        <info>
            <ref rid="29" obj-type="Unknown"/>
        </info>
    </term>
    <term id="03">
        <name>
            <value>yellow</value>
        </name>
    </term>
    <term id="04">
        <name>
            <value>red</value>
        </name>
        <info>
            <ref rid="40" obj-type="Hotel"/>
        </info>
        <info>
            <ref rid="41" obj-type="Building"/>
        </info>
        <info>
            <ref rid="43" obj-type="House"/>
        </info>
    </term>
       <term id="05">
        <name>
            <value>purple</value>
        </name>
    </term>
    <term id="06">
        <name>
            <value>magenta</value>
        </name>

        <info>
            <ref rid="60" obj-type="Building"/>
        </info>
        <info>
            <ref rid="62" obj-type="Unknown"/>
        </info>
        <info>
            <ref rid="64" obj-type="House"/>
        </info>
    </term>
</thesaurus>
```

> What I want is this:
>
> 1) Select all `<term>` tags that without an `<info>` tag. This is
>   already accomplished with the first apply-templates:
>   *select="term[not(info)]"* in the XSLT below.
>
> 2) Select all `<term>` tags when its `<ref>` tag contains an
>   `obj-type="Unknown"` alone or multiple times, but don't select it if
>   it's surrounded by `obj-types` with values different than "*Unknown*"
>   (like Building or House).
>
> *** Inside an `<info>` tag, when having `obj-type` siblings with other values, 
>   it takes at least one value of 'Unknown' for the `<term>` tag to not
>   be selected.

---

If the XSLT works well, the  tags selected will be:

02, 03, 05

where:

> 01 won't be selected because it contains `<info>` tags, and none of those tags has a obj-type='Unknown'
>
> 02 will be selected because there are three multiple values of 'Unknown', and
>   no other values different than 'Unknown'
>
> 03 will be selected because it does not contains `<info>` tags
>
> 04 won't be selected because it contains `<info>` tags with `obj-type` values different than 'Unknown'.
>
> 05 will be selected because there are no info tags.
>
> 06 won't be selected because although there is one value of 'Unknown',
>   all the other `<ref>` siblings have a value `obj-type` different than 'Unknown'.
>
> *** REMEMBER: Inside an `<info>` tag, when having `obj-type` siblings with other values, it takes at least one value of 
>   'Unknown' for the `<term>` tag to not be selected.

---

I'm using the XSLT below. With the first **apply-templates** I can select all the  tags without an `<info>` tag.

With the second **apply-templates** I can select all the `<term>` tags that contain a `<ref>` tag with an `obj-type="Unknown"`, but I don't know how to tell the XSLT that if there are obj-types with a different value, don't select the corresponding `<term>` tag.

I tried to use a for-each and a conditional, to iterate through all the `<ref>` children and check whether one of the siblings had a different value than 'Unknown' to not select its `<term>` parent, but to no avail.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" > 
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/thesaurus">       

     <xsl:apply-templates select="term[not(info)]"/>

     <xsl:apply-templates select="term[info/ref[@obj-type='Unknown']]"/>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="term">

      <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>  

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="term[info/ref]">

       <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
       <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
       <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
       <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try selecting the terms who doesn't contain something other than `Unknown`

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="term[not(info/ref[@obj-type!='Unknown'])]"/>
```

Or adding an if statement in your `term[info/ref]` template

```
<xsl:template match="term[info/ref]">
    <xsl:if test="not(info/ref[@obj-type!='Unknown'])">
       <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
       <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
       <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
       <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
       <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much for taking your time to go through this code. I knew it was something that simple. I tried to use an IF but couldn't properly construct it in XSLT terms. Thanks again.